# Getting this error: Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Tags: java, groovy

```
import com.itko.lisa.vse.stateful.model.TransientResponse;
import com.itko.lisa.vse.stateful.model.Response;
import com.itko.util.ParameterList;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.String;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
import groovy.util.logging.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Softwares/LISA/CBO_CurrentBalance1/Data/BalanceReport.xlsx");  
    //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/lisa-user/Data/CBOPayment.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");        
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();                  
        AccountNumber1  = testExec.getStateObject("AccountNumber1")
        AccountNumber2 = testExec.getStateObject("AccountNumber2")

        if (AccountNumber1 == cells.next().getStringCellValue()) {
           if(cells.hasNext()) {
             Balance = cells.next().getNumericCellValue();                               
             testExec.setStateValue("Balance1", Balance);                      
           }
        }

        if (AccountNumber2 == cells.next().getStringCellValue()) {
            if (cells.hasNext()) {
                Balance = cells.next().getNumericCellValue();                               
                testExec.setStateValue("Balance2", Balance);                   
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is not a complete example, after the imports there has to be a class declaration like `public class MyClass { ... }` and the logic should be in a method. Concerning your question topic: You are reading the cell value by using `getStringCellValue()` always, but Excel has different cell formattings and types, that means you should either know which column contains numerics and read them by `getStringDoubleValue()` (for example, there are even more cell types) or you — better — check for the cell type before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

**you need something like this :**
*don't get confused with the naming convention as this is one of my code.
the problem is*

> ```
>     DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
>     String _charges = fmt.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(45).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("D")));
> ```

what you are doing is trying to fetch a numeric value from the sheet whereas it is saved as a String so you need to convert it to String before you can use it. The code i have pasted is not the exact solution but i hope you might get the hint about the solution.

Comment: but the same code is written for first If(), there it is working. It should work for next if().

Comment: i dnt know exactly how the values in the excel are saved , but when you code it should be in common data type so its better to add this covert , so it should work in every case